# Verilog - Waiting for combinational logic to complete

Tags: verilog

I have some combinational logic `f` that depends on a register `r` like this:

```
reg r;
assign output = f(r); // f is a complicated function of r
```

Now, I want to change `r` and use `output`.  I want something like:

```
always begin
    r = r + 1;
    if(output) begin
        // do something
    end
end
```

In simulation, I could add `#100`, for example, between `r = r + 1` and `if(output)` to achieve what I want.  However, `#100` is not synthesizable.  Will the hardware have some sort of delay inserted automatically?  If not, how can I wait for the combinational logic to finish?

Answer (score 1):

In the very general case, you could set up your logic to behave asynchronously with respect to `r` and `output` where they have a combinational loop between them (ie, `output` is the output of a combinational function of `r` and `r` is the output of a combinational function of `output`, forming a loop). However, this design is hard to deal with for a number of reasons and requires very detailed and specific timing and other properties (things like stable states and glitch prevention). If you want to learn more about how this might work, do some research on asynchronous design.

However, based on how you seem to want this circuit to behave, you really want to make a synchronous design. In this case, you probably want to register `r` and run the system off a clock. Such a design might look like this:

```
input      clk; // We need an input clock to run the design
output reg out; // Lets not call it output as thats a keyword in verilog
reg [3:0]  r; // I assume you want r to do more than just flip between 1 and 0, so you need to give it a few more bits of width

assign out = f(r); // figure out the output

// Heres your combinational function of out which does more stuff, not sure if it belongs here or in the parent module, but you'd need to give more info on what you do with out
always @* begin
  if (out) begin
    // Do your thing
  end
end

// The register for r (which acts as a counter in your design)
always @(posedge clk) begin
  r <= r + 4'd1;
end
```

Without more details on your design, I cant really determine if you need more done, but this kind of synchronous design, based of a clock signal which provides your delay, is what you probably should be using.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  What if my function takes more than one clock cycle to compute?  In my case, `out` depends on multiple cryptographic functions.

Comment: @user1887231, for multi-cycle you will need a counter; change `r` when the counter is a s specific value.